# PHP - Webform to csv (splitting commas from field (not wanted))

Tags: php, csv

I have some PHP on my 'website' that I am using to send some data from a webform into a csv file.

It is working, but the field called `'primary_classification'` contains some text which have commas in. With those classifications, it is splitting the text across two cells in the `csv`.

This is the PHP:

```
<?php
    $keys = array('user_name',  'gr_num', 'primary_classification');
    $csv_line = array();
    foreach($keys as $key){
        array_push($csv_line,'' . $_GET[$key]);
    }
    $fname = 'test.csv';
    $csv_line = implode(',',$csv_line);
    if(!file_exists($fname)){$csv_line = "\r\n" . $csv_line;}
    $fcon = fopen($fname,'a');
    $fcontent = $csv_line;
    fwrite($fcon,$csv_line."\n");
    fclose($fcon);

    echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('The classification has been added!')
    window.location.href='http://localhost:8080/classification.html';
    </SCRIPT>");

?>
```

This is the output from the csv when using 'Individual behaviour' (working), and 'Education, learning and skills' (not working).

[image]

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure it is enough if you wrap your fields in quotes, so simply change:

```
array_push($csv_line,'' . $_GET[$key]);
```

into

```
array_push($csv_line, '"' . $_GET[$key] . '"');
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that has fixed the problem! I have only just started using PHP so I am sorry if it was a basic question. Have to start somewhere! I will mark your answer as the correct answer when it lets me (thank you for being so quick!) :)